# Extract information from path name

Tags: matlab, text-extraction

I want to make a script in MATLAB that saves my output data with a certain name. All information for this name is in the path from the input data, like it is shown here:

```
path = 'C:\projektions100\algorithm1\method_A\data1';
projection = 
algorithm =
method =  
data =
```

The script then should extract the text in the path with the keyword (f.e. method) from the adjacent backslashes so the script is more flexible in case I made a spelling mistake with some folder names. 
[This is what I found to extract a text between a start and a end point](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/extractbetween.html) but I cannot simply use the backslashes since there are a few of them in the path.
How should I proceed?

Comment: `dir()` gives you a list of directories, including path names. Then you can use `strsplit()` to separate a string (`dir.folder` in your case), using a backslash as delimiter in your string. Then you have all folder names in separate strings, so you can pick the one you need.

Comment: Thanks! With `k = strfind(C,'argorithm')
algorithm= C(find(~cellfun(@isempty,k)));` I was also able to locate my word

Comment: Great! Note that it's perfectly acceptable on Stack Overflow to post an answer to your own question, just make sure you follow the rules in [answer]. Please do so, as that makes this post easier to find in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `regexp` with named tokens:

```
>> path = 'C:\projektions100\algorithm1\method_A\data1';
>> all=regexp(path,'[^\\]+\\proje[ck]tion(?<projection>[^\\]+)\\algorithm(?<algorithm>[^\\]+)\\method(?<method>[^\\]+)\\data(?<data>.+$)','names')

all = 

  struct with fields:

    projection: 's100'
     algorithm: '1'
        method: '_A'
          data: '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on how to find the end of your keywords. Here is a bit code, which loops through the keywords and looks for them in the path (stored in `p2fldr`, because the variable `path` returns the working path in MATLAB and you overshadow it if you define it).

```
p2fldr = 'C:\projektions100\algorithm1\method_A\data1';

% keywords
kyWrd = {'projection','algorithm','method','data'};
Tag = cell(size(kyWrd));
for i = 1:length(kyWrd)
    % get keyword
    ky = kyWrd{i};
    % look for it in the path
    idx = strfind(p2fldr,ky);
    if ~isempty(idx)
        % remaining path
        idx_offset = idx+strlength(ky);
        prm = p2fldr(idx_offset:end);
        % look for file separator '\'
        idx_tmp = strfind(prm,filesep);
        % if you don't find one, it is pabably the last entry, so take the
        % length
        if isempty(idx_tmp)
            idx_tmp = length(prm)+1;
        end
        % this is the index where it ends
        idx2 = idx_tmp(1)-1;

        % assign to tag-cell
        Tag{i} = prm(1:idx2);
    end
end
```

You can build a shortcut if you know that they are always in the last 4 entries of your path, so you can use `strsplit` right away and index the last returned cells

```
str_splt = strsplit(p2fldr,filesep);
Tag = cell(size(kyWrd));
for i = 1:length(kyWrd)
    % index cells
    str = str_splt{end-length(kyWrd)+i};
    % get keyword
    ky = kyWrd{i};
    Tag{i} = str(length(ky)+1:end);
end
```

Note that this does not care if it matches your keywords (e.g. your path says `'projektions'`  but I defined the keyword to be `'projection'`)